# Kentico Access PageType table values from code behind

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

I have created a new page type called "HeroHeader". I can see that in the database it created a table for that new page type.

[image]

Is there a way I can access this table data from a webpart code behind?

Some thing like

```
var record = GetPageTypeData("HeroHeader");
var colValueById = record["HeaderId"][1];
```

Comment: you can just use the pages API - https://docs.kentico.com/api12sp/content-management/pages and use the DocumentHelper.GetDocuments() with the .WithCoupledColumns to get the page object data including the coupled data - https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/custom-development/working-with-pages-in-the-api/page-database-structure

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Check out the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k12/developing-websites/developing-web-parts/working-with-web-part-properties) for starters.   You creat public properties in your web part which access properties in your code.  Then in your code you use [Document  Queries](https://docs.kentico.com/k12/custom-development/working-with-pages-in-the-api) to get code from page data. This is all done using C# code.

You can also use Kentico K# Macro syntax to get page data.  Something like `{%CurrentDocument.GetValue("ColumnName")%}` will get the value of that pages field.

If you're new to Kentico you might want to [check out the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k12/developing-websites/portal-engine-development-overview) how to use web parts and how to configure your site